# why does react only invoke state change after the second time I unfocus the input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

in this code I want react to start validating only after I leave the field for the first time, yet it only does after the second time (focus => blur => focus => blur). why is this happening ?

```js
const BasicForm = (props) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState("");
    const [emailEntered, setEmailEntered] = useState(false);

    function validateEmail() {
        const formatCheck = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/.test(
            email
        );
        const emptyCheck = email.trim() !== "";

        if (emailEntered) {
            if (!formatCheck) {
                setEmailError(
                    `email can only contain letters, numbers, . , _ also it must end with a @ + domain`
                );
            }
            if (!emptyCheck) {
                setEmailError("email can't be empty");
            }
            if (formatCheck && emptyCheck) {
                setEmailError("");
            }
        }
    }

    function handleEmailChange(event) {
        const emailInput = event.target.value;
        setEmail(emailInput);
        validateEmail();
    }

    function handleEmailBlur() {
        setEmailEntered(true);
        validateEmail();
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={}>
            <div className="control-group">
            <div className="form-control">
                <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail Address</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={handleEmailChange}
                    onBlur={handleEmailBlur}
                />
                {emailError && <small>{emailError}</small>}
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

I inspected the component state in the browser and on first blur it does change the `emailEntered` to true but the `emailError` is still empty. it only changes after the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Because `validateEmail` does not have the correct state value after you've called `setEmailEntered(true);` so it will skip the `if (emailEntered)` part.

Consider just settings `setEmailEntered` in the function, and use a `useEffect` to check a change on that so you can call the `validateEmail` function.

Same goes for the `onChange` handler, the `validate` won't have the new function.

To combine those, make the `useEffect` look for both `emailEntered` and `email` to call the validate function.

---

Check out the demo with the fixes mentioned above:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const BasicForm = (props) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState("");
    const [emailEntered, setEmailEntered] = useState(false);

    function validateEmail() {
        const formatCheck = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/.test(
            email
        );
        const emptyCheck = email.trim() !== "";

        if (emailEntered) {
            if (!formatCheck) {
                setEmailError(
                    `email can only contain letters, numbers, . , _ also it must end with a @ + domain`
                );
            }
            if (!emptyCheck) {
                setEmailError("email can't be empty");
            }
            if (formatCheck && emptyCheck) {
                setEmailError("");
            }
        }
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (emailEntered || email) {
            validateEmail();
        }
    }, [ email, emailEntered ]);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={null}>
            <div className="control-group">
                <div className="form-control">
                    <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail Address</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        onBlur={() => setEmailEntered(true)}
                    />
                    {emailError && <small>{emailError}</small>}
                </div>
              </div>
        </form>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<BasicForm />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```